# Software (Nuke 11.0.v1) quits unexpectedly Mac Pro 1.1 running macOS v10.11.6 (El Capitan)

Tags: software

I have tried several times to open the Foundry Nuke (11.v01). Nuke closes unexpectedly just after starting it. My MacPro meets the system requirements for that version of Nuke. Does it have something to do with the 32-bit EFI of MacPro Pro 1.1? With previous versions I don't have any problems.

When I’ve tried to launch Nuke in verbose or safe mode from the terminal, "Illegal instruction: 4" appears in both cases.
Process:               Nuke11.0v1 [47687]
Path:                  /Applications/Nuke11.0v1/NukeX11.0v1.app/NukeX11.0v1
Identifier:            uk.co.thefoundry.NukeX11.0v1
Version:               11.0.1.21 (11.0.1.21)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Nuke11.0v1 [47687]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2023-06-25 18:11:05.656 +0200
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11.6 (15G31)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        17E24410-AF6D-B965-58B7-C01AF443E8F0

Sleep/Wake UUID:       F76F3A0D-82BB-429A-8A10-5579EF4A93F2

Time Awake Since Boot: 31000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       5300 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
/Applications/Nuke11.0v1/Nuke11.0v1.app/Contents/MacOS//libcom-api.dylib

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libcom-api.dylib                0x0000000111f78dc4 AAFObjectModel::SortDefinitions() + 276
1   libcom-api.dylib                0x0000000111f79fb9 AAFObjectModel::InitializeDefinitions() + 25
2   dyld                            0x00007fff665f810b ImageLoaderMachO::doModInitFunctions(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 265
3   dyld                            0x00007fff665f8284 ImageLoaderMachO::doInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 40
4   dyld                            0x00007fff665f48bd ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) + 305
5   dyld                            0x00007fff665f4852 ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) + 198
6   dyld                            0x00007fff665f4743 ImageLoader::processInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) + 127
7   dyld                            0x00007fff665f49b3 ImageLoader::runInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) + 75
8   dyld                            0x00007fff665e9eb0 dyld::runInitializers(ImageLoader*) + 89
9   dyld                            0x00007fff665f1308 dlopen + 555
10  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff9c2de79c dlopen + 59
11  uk.co.thefoundry.NukeX11.0v1    0x000000010f851b54 mainLinux(int, char**, char const*, char const*) + 324
12  uk.co.thefoundry.NukeX11.0v1    0x000000010f851957 main + 23
13  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff9c2df5ad start + 1

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
rax: 0x0000000112216060  rbx: 0x0000000111f861b0  rcx: 0x0000000000000000  rdx: 0x0000000112216060
rdi: 0x00000001122070a0  rsi: 0x0000000112206fe0  rbp: 0x00007fff503abde0  rsp: 0x00007fff503abdb0
r8: 0x0000000112206fe0   r9: 0x0000000112216060  r10: 0x000000010f8a4a18  r11: 0x0000000000000000
r12: 0x00000001121b4a60  r13: 0x000000011220f610  r14: 0x0000000112219eb0  r15: 0x0000000000000001
rip: 0x0000000111f78dc4  rfl: 0x0000000000010206  cr2: 0x000000011215b050

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x00000000
Trap Number:     6

Heading

Heading